# Why is the Android app that I developed not updating automatically through Google Play?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I developed an Android application, and I am testing it to ensure that it updates properly through Google Play. Unfortunately, I have encountered quite a bit of difficulties.

I have auto-updates on. I have a working Wi-Fi connection. The new version of the app does not require any new permissions, yet it simply refuses to auto-update correctly. Instead, I get the following notification at the top:

> 2 updates need approval with the text "3 updates total are pending" beneath it.

As I stated beforehand, the new version of my app does not need new permissions and thus not approval. Why is it pending, then?

I have tried to clear the data and cache from the Google Play Store app and Google Play Services app, but it still will not auto-update.

It is very important that this app correctly updates as needed, but I am a bit at a loss what to do. I would sincerely appreciate any help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the following notification at the top "2 updates need approval" with the text "3 updates total are pending" beneath it.

This is because (in this case two) one or more applications that needs updating also need new permissions. Auto-updating of apps actually relies on that all apps that needs updating at can be updated instantly and doesn't need to be approved because they have new permissions. Two of three apps needs new permissions. That means there are two other apps that need new permissions.

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly, the fact that two need new permissions is preventing the one that does need new permissions (my app), from auto-updating? If so, is there a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: If you have 5 apps that need updating, and one needs new permissions you have to approve that one before the rest can be updated. No by-passing, but the user gets the notification so it gets updated. You can relax. I develop apps myself and in my experience, it takes at most one day from the update goes live to the users have updated. Some people don't like to update some apps though and some people have turned off automatic updates. Make sure there are no other updates, download the developer console app and make another update and you will see it updates automatically. No way around it